# SimpleXMLElement returns Empty Object

Tags: php, xml

As simple as the sun light:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<string>-2|-2|635705730515209906|7F2ShUrAQFJmvxTxVgkm2yjghWorOaZe/g==</string>');
             var_dump($xml->{"string"});die();
```

It prints:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#67 (0) { }
```

I would expect the content of "string" node...
If I do

```
var_dump($xml);
```

I get:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#66 (1) { [0]=> string(61) "-2|-2|635705730515209906|7F2ShUrAQFJmvxTxVgkm2yjghWorOaZe/g==" }
```

But how to get the node "string" ?

Comment: remove the: `->{"string"}` part ...

Comment: Not sure, perhaps you wanted to do that instead? http://3v4l.org/abA1D . (using xpath)

Comment: And if you have 2 root level nodes? <string1>A</string1><string2>B</string2>?

Comment: If you have two root level nodes, problem solved: you cannot use SimpleXML to work with malformed XML because, technically, it isn't XML. I removed my answer when I saw you had made an edit so I had the chance to verify but, honestly, I don't understand why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: As far as I know, if you don't have a "root" parent element, you cannot directly access such nodes "directly", because the XML is not "valid". By adding a <root>, however, you can just access using ->string or ->string1 and so on. http://3v4l.org/69pmZ Can you add <root> and </root> at the beginning and end of your document or are you loading that XML externally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top level element (aka root node) is always implicit. You also need to cast to a scalar type or you'll get the object itself. Combined:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<string>-2|-2|635705730515209906|7F2ShUrAQFJmvxTxVgkm2yjghWorOaZe/g==</string>');
var_dump((string)$xml);
```

[Online demo](http://3v4l.org/GLnSH).